# How to prepare RStudio environment so that my local variable of the attributes table of shapefile can be adequately taken by shinyapps.io?

Tags: shiny, rstudio

Following code uses **shiny** and **rgdal** libraries for developing a shiny application in **RStudio**. This app displays a **sidebarPanel** with **choices** options of **selectInput** taken arbitrarily from ls("package:datasets"). I used this arbitrary list for corroborating that this widget works as expected. Application also displays at the main panel, a graphs of a test shapefile. The shapefile was stored in **shapes** folder of the App and it can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kd9kssnlf9e9nm6/polygon8b.zip?dl=0).

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(rgdal)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # img(src="pc.png", width='100%', height=400),
    # 
    # titlePanel(h1("Emergencias 2022, Protección Ciudadana", align="center", style='color:#0d5728')),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("emergencias", label = h1("Emergencias", style='color:#0d5728'), choices= ls("package:datasets")),
            width = 4,
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            width = 4,
            plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")
        )
        
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output)  {

    #setwd('C:/Users/zeito/Desktop/shiny/example_PC4/')
    
    test <- readOGR('shapes/polygon8.shp')
        
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(
        {
        
            plot(test, 
                 axes=T, 
                 col= 'blue',
                 xlab= 'longitud',
                 ylab = 'latitud',
                 main= "PC_emergencias_2022")
            
        }
        
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

When the application is run locally, result can be observed below (I commented the lines for displaying a banner to summarize the code).

[image]

The same application (in this case with the referred banner) can be uploaded without any problem in my **shinyapps.io** free plan; as it can be observed in the link below.

https://zeito.shinyapps.io/example_PC4/

However, I want to display at the combo box of the **sidebarPanel** the unique values from emergencia field of the shapefile. Code looks as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(rgdal)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # img(src="pc.png", width='100%', height=400),
    # 
    # titlePanel(h1("Emergencias 2022, Protección Ciudadana", align="center", style='color:#0d5728')),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("emergencias", label = h1("Emergencias", style='color:#0d5728'), choices= test$emergencia),
            width = 4,
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            width = 4,
            plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")
        )
        
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output)  {
    
    test <- readOGR('shapes/polygon8.shp')
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(
        {
            
            plot(test, 
                 axes=T, 
                 col= 'blue',
                 xlab= 'longitud',
                 ylab = 'latitud',
                 main= "PC_emergencias_2022")
            
        }
        
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Code works locally; as it can be observed below.

[image]

It produces an error when it is deployed in **shinyapps.io**, however, there is not any error in the Deploy Tab of **RStudio** (see below).

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 7932131...DONE
Deploying bundle: 6664527 for application: 7932131 ...
Waiting for task: 1258938216
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 7859028
  deploying: Starting instances
  success: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to https://zeito.shinyapps.io/example_PC5/
Deployment completed: https://zeito.shinyapps.io/example_PC5/
```

I tried out several suggestion found out in Internet as: comment some lines in the code, convert the **SpatialPointsDataFrame** object in **data.table** and other without any success. I'm new using **RStudio** and, at this time, I would like to know how to prepare the environment in **RStudio** so that my local variable of the attributes table of shapefile can be adequately taken by **shinyapps.io**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple: to move `test <- readOGR('shapes/polygon8.shp')` after libraries as follows.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(rgdal)

test <- readOGR('shapes/polygon8.shp')

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # img(src="pc.png", width='100%', height=400),
    # 
    # titlePanel(h1("Emergencias 2022, Protección Ciudadana", align="center", style='color:#0d5728')),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("emergencias", label = h1("Emergencias", style='color:#0d5728'), choices= ls("package:datasets")),
            width = 4,
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            width = 4,
            plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")
        )
        
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output)  {

    #setwd('C:/Users/zeito/Desktop/shiny/example_PC4/')
       
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(
        {
        
            plot(test, 
                 axes=T, 
                 col= 'blue',
                 xlab= 'longitud',
                 ylab = 'latitud',
                 main= "PC_emergencias_2022")
            
        }
        
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

When I was learning or debugging the code, I loaded several variables in R console and they remain there as local variables.

When the code was ran locally, variable test was always found. However, at the deployment, inside the server function, it will never be found by **shinyapps.io**. Now, during the debugging, I purge all local variables previous to launch the application. If it run successfully, the deployment probably it will be too.